# How to hide Navigation Bar on Tabbed Page MAUI?

Tags: maui

How to hide Navigation Bar on Tabbed Page MAUI?

HasNavigationBar = "False" works on other types of pages(Shell, NavigationPage), but TabbedPage does not contain such a property, how do I hide the NavigationBar?
This is what my App.xaml.cs looks like.

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()); 
    }
}
```

This is what my MainPage.xaml.cs looks like.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
            xmlns:mac="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.macOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
            x:Class="KiberMain.MainPage"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:KiberMain.Pages;assembly=KiberMain"
            BackgroundColor="#ff494f55"
            NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
            mac:TabbedPage.TabsStyle="Icons"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <pages:MusicPage IconImageSource="music1" BackgroundColor="#ff494f55"/>
        <pages:RadioPage IconImageSource="micro1" BackgroundColor="#ff494f55"/>
        <pages:InfoPage IconImageSource="info1" BackgroundColor="#ff494f55"/>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At the moment, your question doesn't contain a lot of details. Please show some code (as text) and a screenshot of what it currently looks like. This will help solve your problem faster.

Comment: Can you please show what it looks like at the moment?

Comment: Do your child pages have a title? There is a known bug in MAUI: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13807 You may need to remove the title of the child pages, if they have one.

Comment: TabbedPage is different from the NavigationPage and Shell. You cannot set the `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` to control the Tabbar. Actually, TabbedPage does not has the property to control the visibility of the tabbar. You can refer to this [TabbedPage Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.tabbedpage?view=net-maui-7.0) for more details.

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT The problem is not the Tab Bar. The **Navigation Bar** (where it also has the title *"KiberStudio"*) comes from the NavigationPage. If the `MainPage` is directly set to a TabbedPage, there is no Navigation Bar and the Title doesn't appear. This is either a bug or a missing feature in MAUI. It should be possible to hide the Navigation Bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `TabbedPage` lives inside a `NavigationPage` container, e.g. by setting it like this:

```cs
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MyTabbedPage());
```

Then you can use `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` on the **child pages** to hide the navigation bar:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
            xmlns:mac="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.PlatformConfiguration.macOSSpecific;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls"
            x:Class="KiberMain.MainPage"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:KiberMain.Pages;assembly=KiberMain"
            BackgroundColor="#ff494f55"
            NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
            mac:TabbedPage.TabsStyle="Icons"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <pages:MusicPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" IconImageSource="music1" BackgroundColor="#ff494f55"/>
        <pages:RadioPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" IconImageSource="micro1" BackgroundColor="#ff494f55"/>
        <pages:InfoPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" IconImageSource="info1" BackgroundColor="#ff494f55"/>
    </TabbedPage.Children>

</TabbedPage>
```

This seems a bit too complicated, because the TabbedPage should be able to decide whether or not to show the Navigation Bar at all. Since setting `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"` directly on the TabbedPage doesn't work, I filed a bug in the MAUI GitHub repository: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16816.

If the child pages of your *TabbedPage* have their `Title` property set, you might also need to unset/remove those assignments for the navigation bar to disappear. There seems to be a bug related to that at the time of writing: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13807

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I updated the question, please take a look.

Comment: @Nikita I've updated my answer. Please check if it works like that.

Comment: The Title property is not set for more than one TabbedPage child, I tried to set Title as x:null, this also does not give results, I also tried to install HasNavigationBar from C#, by the way, your last updated code is not working.

Comment: Try not setting the Title at all, not even using `x:Null`.

Comment: @Nikita I've updated my answer again. It seems that setting it directly on the TabbedPage doesn't work, but when the child pages attempt to hide the navigation bar, it should work. I tested it myself in a blank project with a TabbedPage.

Comment: Using a tabbed page as the first page - a page placed in the constructor of the navigation page, and not a page you navigate to. Navigation bar was hidden when the child pages of the TabbedPage used the had the attached property `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"`.

Comment: It's not about what is shown in the navigation bar, but that it's visible in the first place, while it shouldn't be.

Comment: Doing as the answer said, the navigation bar was hidden on first load. I also used `HasNavigationBar = "False"` on the NavigaitonPage. I'm not sure if that helped or not, but I don't have a navigation bar with the tabs.

Comment: Which platform are you on? This seems to affect Android only - see the link to the bug report I added to the answer.

Comment: I am using android and .NET Maui with .net 6.0

Comment: I meant which device/target platform (Android, iOS, Windows)?

Comment: I am targeting `Android 5.0 (API Level 21 - Lollipop)`

Comment: might be a regression then, we shall see when the ticket is triaged

Comment: Quick update, I targeted `Android 13.0 (API Level 33)` and it worked. I have not tried API 34.